# prove $f(x,y) = ax+by$ if and only if $bf_x = af_y$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

prove $f(x,y) = ax+by$ if and only if  $bf_x = af_y$ also $a,b \neq 0$ and $f$ is $ C^1$ function.

I've got no idea what to do.　I've tried  total derivative of $f$ or something like that. I'm also thinking that by being $C^1$ and $bf_x = af_y$ can we conclude that $x$ and $y$ must be separated and both need to have a degree of $1$, but I don't think that seems  legit.

Comment: One direction is very straightforward.  If $f(x,y)= ax+by$ then it's easy to compute $bf_x$ and $af_y$.

Comment: $*$ is time $bf_x = af_y$ sorry for the confusion

Comment: yeah the other way round's the problem

Comment: Let $v = (b, -a) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. Then the equation $bf_x = af_y$ is equivalent to $D_v f = 0$, where $D_v$ is the directional derivative toward the direction $v$. So any function of the form $f(x,y) = g(ax+by)$ for some $g \in C^1(\Bbb{R})$ is a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The "other way" is not true: $f(x,y)=e^{x+y}$

We have $f_x=f_y$

Answer (score 1):

=> direction - it is trivial

<=  direction

See $g(t) = f(c_1 + bt, c_2 - at)$.

$g_t(t) = bf_x(c_1 + bt, c_2 - at) - af_y(c_1 + bt, c_2 - at) = 0$

So, $f(x,y) = h(a*x + b*y)$, where h is $C^1$ function.